# How to Display Dates inserted on Sqlite Database on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

i was developing a sales app for project in which user inserts item, price and qty sold with auto timeStamp in Sqlite Database and user sees sold items in recyclerView. The insertion of data including time stamp was working fine. To populate sales database values including salesdate in recyclerView i have used Parcelabel but when i open sold items list error emerges from COLUMN_SOLD_DATE with error message "Couldn't read row 0, col -1"  i have inserted time on belows code. So how to populate all sales table data on RecyclerView including date?

ContentValues contentValues =  new ContentValues();

```
contentValues.put(SALES.COLUMN_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());

sqLiteDatabase.insert(SALES.TABLE_SALES,null,contentValues);
```

to populate on sales items on RecyclerView i have used the code below

```
private void LoadFromDb()
{ 
 final String[] salesColn = {
                SALES.COLUMN_QUANTITY_SOLD,
                SALES.COLUMN_DATE,
                SALES.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID,
                SALES._ID};

        final Cursor salesCursor = db.query(SALES.TABLE_SALES, salesColn,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        loadSalesFromDatabase(salesCursor);
    }

    private static void loadSalesFromDatabase(Cursor cursor) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int salesAmountPos = cursor.getColumnIndex(SALES.COLUMN_QUANTITY_SOLD);
        int salesDate = cursor.getColumnIndex(SALES.COLUMN_DATE);
        int productidpos = cursor.getColumnIndex(SALES.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID);
        int idPos = cursor.getColumnIndex(SALES._ID);

        DataManager dm = getInstance();
        dm.mSales.clear();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(salesDate);
            sb.append(calendar.getTime().toString());
            String Samount = cursor.getString(salesAmountPos);
            String sdate = sb.toString();
            String pid = cursor.getString(productidpos);
            int id = cursor.getInt(idPos);


            ProdcutInfo sales = dm.getProducts(pid);
            SalesInfo salesInfo= new SalesInfo(id, sales, Samount, sdate);
            dm.mNotes.add(salesInfo);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can add data you want to display in sqlite database in one arraylist and get data from that arraylist by using Adapter, Adapter as a mediator for getting Dates,For that Store Dates in adapter first and adapter will take it to recycle view.It performs like below,

```
public class RecycleCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleCustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<DataDemo> eventsArrayList;
private Context context;

public RecycleCustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataDemo> eventsArrayList,Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.eventsArrayList = eventsArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecycleCustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_events_rowlayout,parent,false);
    return  new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleCustomAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final DataDemo dataDemo = eventsArrayList.get(position);
    viewHolder.event_name.setText(dataDemo.getName());
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView event_name;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        event_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventsArrayList.size();
}
```

}

In this onBindViewHolder will  hold view to perform an operation

I hope this may will help you!!